# How could I shuffle and then display a random card from this array?

Tags: javascript

```
class Card {
   constructor(suit, value) {  
    this.suit = suit;  
    this.value = value;
    }
}
```

TEST IF IT LETS ME MAKE A CARD

```
let card = new Card('Spades', 8);
console.log(card);
```

// MAKE A DECK OF 52 CARDS

```
class Deck {
    constructor () {
        this.deck =  [];  
    }
    createDeck (suits, values) {
        for(let suit of suits) {
            for(let value of values){
                this.deck.push(new Card (suit, value));
            }
        }
        return this.deck;


    }
}
const suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades'];
const values = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
let deck = new Deck();
deck.createDeck(suits, values);
// console.log(deck);
```

I can create the deck I just dont know how to pick random items fom it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

since the created deck instance is attached to the deck variable you can access it by doing `deck.deck`.

so you can do something like:

```
deck.deck[Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)]
```

you can also use the Math.round function instead, depends on how precise you want to be

you could also create a function where you then pass your deck and get a card back. for example:

```
function pickCard(deck) {
  return deck[Math.round(Math.random() * 52))];
}
```

you can implement this as a method as well

```
    class Deck{
     // ...your code
     get pickCard() {
      return this.deck[Math.round(Math.random() * 52)];
     }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but it still isnt working do you think you could clarify? @voiys

Comment: If you used the get method you call it by using deck.pickCard, not deck.pickCard()

Comment: when I tried to run the funcition pickCard nothing was returned

Comment: If you want to use it as a regular method (with parentheses) just remove the get keyword

Comment: Ah you need to pass deck.deck to function pickCard(deck)

Comment: and how would that look like?

Comment: I am sorry for all the questions I am kind of new to this

Comment: If youre using my function example call it like this -> pickCard(deck.deck), if youre using my class example (with get method) call it like this -> deck.pickCard, if youre using my other class example (still a method you just remove get keyword) use it like this -> deck.pickCard()

Comment: Its ok, imo its important to understand classes really well so ask away